# NSMutableArray empty array error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I am doing some operations in for loop with nsmutablearray' s data. But sometimes it work sometimes it gives me an error like 'array index 3 empty array' at this line :

```
else if (min>[[enyakinarray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue])
```

full code :

```
for (int i=0; i<[ws3.CustomerID count]; i++) {

    //radian hesaplaması
    float total = [first floatValue];
    float theta = total * M_PI/180;
    float total2 = [second floatValue];
    float theta2 = total2 * M_PI/180;
    float total3 = [[ws3.Latitude objectAtIndex: i]  floatValue];
    float theta3 = total3 * M_PI/180;
    float total4 = [[ws3.Longitude objectAtIndex: i] floatValue];
    float theta4 = total4 * M_PI/180;


     distance = 6371 * acos(cos(theta) * cos(theta3)
                           * cos(theta4 - theta2)
                           + sin(theta) * sin( theta3)) ;

    NSLog(@"xxxxx %f",distance);

    num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance];
    [enyakinarray  addObject:num];
    NSLog(@"asasasas %@",enyakinarray);

}

float min;
NSString *s;
for (int i=0; i<[enyakinarray count]; i++) {
   if(i==0)
   { 
    min = [[enyakinarray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    s= [ws3.CustomerName objectAtIndex:i];
   } 
   else if (min>[[enyakinarray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue])
            {
            min= [[enyakinarray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
            s = [ws3.CustomerName objectAtIndex:i];
            }
    enyakinfirma.text=s;
   }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that `ws3.CustomerName` contains `[enyakinarray count]` objects?

Comment: What comes out from the log statement?

Comment: `array index 3 empty array` doesn't sound like a real error message, please post the exact message you're encountering.

Comment: yes the ws3.CustomerName's count is equal to enyakinarray' s count.

Comment: Ok I will write exact error message but application sometimes gives me sometimes works I said. The log statements are enyakinarray' s index value so distances.

Comment: I give this error at  s= [ws3.CustomerName objectAtIndex:i];
 line  'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: Well, what it's saying is that ws3.CustomerName only contains 2 entires, and you're requiring there to be 7.  Apparently there's no guarantee that ws3.CustomerName contains the same number of entries as enyakinarray.

Comment: But sometimes it gives me this error sometimes work. How can you explain that? Also, ws3.CustomerName and enyakinarray have same entry count.

Comment: Why it gives me sometimes this error? Is there anybody know this error??? Because sometimes it works.

Comment: Maybe you're setting the array capacity dynamically and sometimes it sets the capacity as good to not crash and sometimes it doesn't. Or maybe you're using the initWithCapacity: but that only reserves the memory for array, not initialize the array positions, which makes you get the "array index 3 empty array", initialized value at index 3 for the array. Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont give the capacity to NSMutableArray. So, it's capacity dynamically. I didnt understand what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: @HacersengulAkac -- Basically your code is broken and you need to debug it.  You assume that the two arrays always have the same number of entries, but obviously your code does not assure that.  You need to apply code inspection and debugging techniques to find out why this "invariant" is not always satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange but should be really easy to debug. Just write

```
NSLog("First array: %@", enyakinarray)
NSLog(@"Second array: %@", ws3.CustomerName)
NSLog(@"Second array: %@", ws3.CustomerID)
```

before your `for` and you should see the problem very quickly. Maybe you are changing the array contents somewhere between its creation and usage?

However, I see a design problem there. Your code uses several separate arrays `CustomerName`, `CustomerID` and `enyakinarray` `Latitude` and `Longitude` which contain values of a single entity Customer (name, id, latitude, longitude and distance). Maybe you could create an object Customer with these properties and mantain only one array of customers? Good OOP design helps you prevent this type of errors :)

And you can merge the two cycles into one:

```
float minDistance = FLT_MAX;
NSUInteger customerIndex = 0;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [ws3.CustomerID count]; i++) {
    /* distance calculation code ... */

    float distance = 6371 * acos(cos(theta) * cos(theta3)
                           * cos(theta4 - theta2)
                           + sin(theta) * sin(theta3));

    if (distance < minDistance) {
        minDistance = distance;
        customerIndex = i;
    }
}

enyakinfirma.text = [ws3.CustomerName objectAtIndex:customerIndex];
```